# Bootstrap modals and SEO

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, seo

My whole website is based on Bootstrap and I've replaced actual pages with [modals](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals). When the visitor clicks on buttons like "About, Contact, ect." a modal will pop up. How can I SEO optimize these? First I thought to display iframes to .html pages (about.html, contact.html) inside the modals, which will only hold the content and meta tags, but if a visitor comes directly on those URLs, they will only see that respective content.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you make a site purely HTML (`Back-end` PHP/ASP/.NET)
without the use of javascript and iframes without (iframes are bad for SEO),
then use `ajax` to grab the content of these subpages and put these modal and other things on your site.

you can also implement paging with `Ajax` in `HASH`.